# Store information from dialog boxes to text file Java

Tags: java, printing

I want to write program that stores information about cars. You input for instance brand and owner name for each car in dialog boxes. In the end, a dialog box with information about all cars should be shown by writing the information to a text file and then reading from it to the dialog box. I create a method getInfo which shows the appropriate boxes correctly.

```
public static void getInfo() {
  boolean done = false;
  do {
     String brand=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Brand?");
     String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Owner?");

     if (brand == null) {
        done = true;

     } else {
        String info ="Car: "+brand+" "+"\nOwner: "+name;
        String message =  " Do you want to input more cars?";
        int buttonClicked = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,      message, "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        done = (buttonClicked == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);

     }
    } while (!done);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  getInfo();
}
```

I am not sure how to add the information to a text file and how to deal with the loops. To write the information to a text file I tried to change the main method to the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (PrintWriter outstream = new PrintWriter
                             (new BufferedWriter
                             (new FileWriter("cars.txt", true)))) {
       getInfo();
       outstream.println(info);
    }
}
```

What am I missing and how can I implement the functionality?

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `BufferedWriter` outside of the loop:

```
File outputFile = new File("path/to/the/file.txt");
if(!outputFile.exists()){
    try {
        outputFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
BufferedWriter bw = null; //this declares a buffer that writes to some stream. 
try{
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile,true));    //here we actually create it, and tell it to write to a file stream, directed at the outputFile file.
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace(); //this is if the file doesn't exist, which shouldn't happen, but we still need to put this here, because better safe than sorry.
}
```

And then in your loop: after the

```
String info ="Car: "+brand+" "+"\nOwner: "+name;
```

do:

```
String info ="Car: "+brand+" "+"\nOwner: "+name;


try {
    bw.write(info);//write the information to the buffer when there's new info. 
    bw.newLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and after exiting the loop, call:

```
bw.close();
```

Comment: I get an error with the file: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory. Should I use some actual location instead of "path/to/the/file.txt"?

Comment: @user30523 yes. Of course. If the path `path/to/the/file.txt` doesn't exist on your computer, then you'll get an error. You need to give a path to a file that can exist. (If it doesn't then the code will create it). for example (on Windows): `"C:\\Users\\<replace this with your username>\\Desktop\\output.txt"`.

Comment: Now it works! However only information about one (the latest) car inputed is printed to the text file, how do I prevent overwriting?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with every loop you are creating a new instance of `info`, so you will lose the information from the previous runs.

In your main method you are accessing `info`, but it should not be known in that scope. What you could do, is to return `info` from the `getInfo()` method.

You should then also think about line breaks and so on, but for a first try this should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public static void main() {
  boolean done = false;
  do {
    Info info = getInfo();
    storeInfo(info);
    done = getDone();
  } while (!done);

  displayInfo();
}

class Info {
  private brand;
  private owner;
}
```

Now you can do single things in each method.

getInfo calls showInputDialog and returns an Info object.

storeInfo stores the Info object to a text file.

getDone calls showInputDialog and returns, if the user wants to quit.

displayInfo opens the text file and shows the info.

The easiest way to implement displayInfo migth be:

```
void displayInfo() {
  // Create a window with TextBox
  // Open the text file
  // Read the content of the text file and add it to the TextBox
}
```

Comment: I added the structure for displayInfo. You do not need the real code, do you?